# apostcardfrom.me - scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope anyone can help me with this.

I want to create the same scroll effect as on this site: http://www.apostcardfrom.me/paigereifler/

Can anyone point me in the right direction where to start or search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of scrolling is often known as **Parallax**

http://desiznworld.com/2013/07/free-jquery-parallax-scrolling-plugins.html